# Minimize functions or files in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My question is that if suppose there are multiple buttons in views suppose it may be 15 and all of these functionality is different so in normal way i have to create multiple files i.e. ajax or php file or i have to create multiple functions in controller.
  Is there any solution to minimise the no of files or functions and implement these functionality in one or two functions or files??

Answer (score 0):

In HTML

```
    <button type="submit" name="submitForm" value="button1">Button 1</button>
     <button type="submit" name="submitForm" value="button2">Button 2</button>   
<button type="submit" name="submitForm" value="button3">Button 3</button>
```

And in controller

```
$formSubmit = $this->input->post('submitForm');
if( $formSubmit == 'button1' )
   //button1 functionality
elseif( $formSubmit == 'button2' )
     //button2 functionality
elseif( $formSubmit == 'button3' )
     //button3 functionality
```

Comment: Thank You Praveen, It works fine but i have another query can we use hash tag to load view in ci if yes then how??

Comment: Ask another question bro... if my answer satisfies you accept it as answer :)